# Changing color of rightCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Somehow my rightCalloutAccessoryView is not visible this is how it looks for me:

[image]

The button is there on the right but it's white. How do I change the color of it? From what I know it's supposed to be blue usually.

This is my code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
        anView!.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.InfoLight) as! UIView
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    return anView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found the answer. This is how I did it.

```
var calloutButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
calloutButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-right.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
calloutButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(51/255.0), green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)
```

I just had to call the buttons tintColor apparently.